# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Sry for my stupid question, but i can`t search answer for my promlem.
*TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ width: number; height: number; title: string; }'*

```
let menu:{width:number; height:number; title:string} = {
width: 200,
height: 300,
title: 'My menu',
 }
function multiplyNumeric(menu:{width:number; height: number; title: string}):void {

for (let k in menu){
    if (typeof menu[k] === "number"){
        menu[k] = Number(menu[k]) * 2;
    }
}
}
multiplyNumeric(menu);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't know what `k` means in the context of the `for` loop inside the `multiplyNumeric` function.

Since the type of `Menu` is strictly defined, and you are determining the value of `Menu` at run-time, you will need to add an additional generic to prop type to `Menu`, like this:

```js
type Menu = {
  width: number;
  height: number;
  title: string;
  [prop: string]: number | string;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

On your multiplyNumeric function the parameter 'menu' has invalid data type. You cannot set like that. From what i understand you want your menu parameter to be an object with three properties

```
{
  width:number; 
  height: number; 
  title: string
}
```

You need to define an interface to do the job.

```
inteface menuObj {
    width:number; 
    height: number; 
    title: string;
}
```

And then do something like this:

```
function multiplyNumeric(menu: menuObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Menu extends Record<string, string | number> {
   width: number,
   height: number,
   title: string,
}
```